# Unable to use classes from unnamed modules after creating module-info.java

Tags: eclipse, maven, java-9, module-info

I'm trying to migrate an old java project to java 9, and preferably try out the new module-info.java functionalities. The project uses maven dependencies, and as far as I can tell, those migrate .jar's as unnamed modules. The project itself runs fine after replacing some depreciated libraries, but a problem arises when I attempt to add a module-info.java file. It's no longer able to interact with any of the maven imports. Is my understanding of the unnamed modules wrong? I thought they are capable of co-existing with named/automatic modules in the same project. If not, why am I unable to import classes from my maven dependencies after creating a module-info.java?

Comment: compile-time or runtime?

Comment: compile time, using mvn clean install

Comment: Hopefully, the `module-info.java` has correct declarative and would be good to look at the maven compiler configuration, your project structure and the content of `module-info.java` in such a case.

Comment: If you're adding a `module-info.java`, you're creating a _named module_. Named modules *can not* read the unnamed module. But Maven (given you're using a recent version of the compiler plugin) knows that and places dependencies on the module path, where they get turned into named modules (explicit or automatic), which means you can read them. Are you sure your `module-info.java` contains all necessary `requires` clauses?

Answer (score 0):

This is because all legacy jars will not be unnamed modules but it will be "automatic" modules. Learnt it the hard way. I had a gson-2.8.5.jar in my classpath and my classes in a module cannot import those classes.
I had to move the jar to module-path and then specify "requires gson;" in the module-info.java of my module to get this working.

Comment: But then do you run into compiler warning "requires directive for an automatic module"? This is a problem if using -Werror.